# How to protect the Backend API against calls other than Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

I have an ASP.NET Core REST API Service hosted on an Azure Web App. I own its source code and I can change it if required.

I am planning to publish REST API Service with Azure API Management.

I am adding Azure AD authentication to the Azure API Management front. So, the API management front is secured. [All the steps are is described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad).

All good so far. **Here is the question (or challange?) :**

Considering that my backend REST API Service is hosted on Azure and publicly accessible, how do I protect it against the request calls other than the API Management Calls?

How the backend service knows the identity and AAD group claims of the incoming call and access to its claims?

A link to a code sample or online documentation would be a great help.

**Update**

While there are some overlaps with the follwoing question:

[How to prevent direct access to API hosted in Azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173908/how-to-prevent-direct-access-to-api-hosted-in-azure-app-service)

... part of this question is still outstanding:

How the backend service knows the identity and AAD group claims of the incoming call and access to its claims?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent direct access to API hosted in Azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173908/how-to-prevent-direct-access-to-api-hosted-in-azure-app-service)

Comment: @MKaz, please see my update.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173908/how-to-prevent-direct-access-to-api-hosted-in-azure-app-service/52174736

Answer (score 0):

You can enable static IP restriction on your WebApp to only allow incoming traffic from the VIP of your APIM Service facing ( keep in mind in some specific scenarios , the VIP may change and will be required to update the whitelist again).

Clients ==> AAD==> VIP APIM Service <==> (VIP APIM allowed) Web App

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions

Comment: How do I know the IP range come from APIM? Is there any official IP list for  Azure Services in every regions?

Comment: Goto to the Overview blade for your API Management instance and look for the "Virtual IP (VIP) addresses" property.  If it lists a private IP address(es), then whitelist those [you are most joined to a VNET], if not whitelist the public address.